# Is there anyway I can email by SQL Management Studio query results in an attachement in a READ ONLY database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I use a (Standby/Read-Only) database in SQL Management Studio to create queries and export data. However now I am trying to set up an automatic email that emails the results out to a select few people daily. I was able to create my query so it pulls my results under the Messages tab and it sends the email, however, the attachment of the results under the Messages tab is not in the email. The error message that shows in the Management Studio states that its because the database is in Standby/Read-Only. Is there a way around this? Is there a way I could save the results I have in a different database that I have write access to and then pull from there?? It is very hard to provide you with a specific query example so willing to work with online or speak over the phone as well!

Comment: Have a look at [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Changing the database to a NON-readonly (write) database is not an option for me. I already tried doing this.

Comment: `sp_send_dbmail` doesn't require the database to be in write; the data relevant to the email is stored in `msdb` not the database you are connected to. Unless `msdb` is in Read-Only, but then the entire instance is unlikely to be functional, so i doubt that.

Comment: Thank you! I will read through this and see what I can find and if it will work for me. I really appreciate the quick response and will let you know what I find out.

Comment: Ok, I believe my problem has to do with I am trying to run my query and email the results all in the same query.. Below is what your attached sp_send_dmail link states:“[ @query = ] 'query' Is a query to execute. The results of the query can be attached as a file, or included in the body of the e-mail message. The query is of type nvarchar(max), and can contain any valid Transact-SQL statements. Note that the query is executed in a separate session, so local variables in the script calling sp_send_dbmail are not available to the query.”

Comment: It states that the query has to be executed in a separate session. How do I do this? Do I have to save my results in a query someplace first and then create a query that pulls from that specific place where I saved them? It looks like they reference AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder  in the example. Was this a specific table that was saved under the same database?

Comment: It doesn't state the query has to be executed in a separate session, it states it will be. it's telling you what is *will* do, but what you need to do.

Comment: First - did you ask anyone at your organization for help. The DBA should be able to assist you in writing a script that can send the results of a query as an email. Setting up the appropriate email information must be done first - and by someone with knowledge and permissions. Then, focus on writing a script that does what you want. There are many examples of doing this on the internet. When that works, you can then focus on automating the process.

Comment: @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder

Comment: Sorry Larnu, can you clarify,... This is where i believe i am going wrong in my query: "@query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder". It looks like in this example they are pulling their query results from AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder".. Is this a table they saved elsewhere??

Comment: EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    "@profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',  
    "@recipients = 'yourfriend@Adventure-Works.com',  
   "@query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder  
                  WHERE DueDate > ''2004-04-30''  
                  AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,  
    "@subject = 'Work Order Count',  
    "@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;”

Comment: SMor, Currently i do not have anyone in my organization that know much about SQL. We are very new to this including myself. However, someone in our IT depart and myself was able to set Database Mail and the appropriate email information correctly because we are able to receive emails. The only problem i am having is those emails do not include the query attachments I need. Basically, i am getting everything in my email above but the query i am trying to attach. I have searched for several hours/days on the internet and not having much luck

Comment: @AmandaWenning  regardless of your solution, you probably should not be sending PHI in an email (at least in the US... beware of HIPAA).

Comment: Who set up your database in the first place? It is clearly an HA replica you are talking about and it does require moderately advanced SQL skills to setup. I suggest you talk to those people, rather than trying to hack your way in, and possibly break something in the process.

Comment: @JenR Thank you for your concern. I am aware of HIPAA.

Comment: @Alex I have been working with the person that set up my database. We have tried many things and now I am using this chat as a last resort since we have very little resources available in our area. Any help would be appreciated.